# Puzzled by the spawned actor from a Spray route

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka, actor, spray

I am doing some Http request processing using Spray. For a request I spin up an actor and send the payload to the actor for processing and after the actor is done working on the payload, I call `context.stop(self)` on the actor to wind the actor down.The idea is to prevent oversaturation of actors on the physical machine.

This is how I have things set up..

In `httphandler.scala`, I have the route set up as follows:

```
path("users"){
   get{
      requestContext => {
         val userWorker = actorRefFactory.actorOf(Props(new UserWorker(userservice,requestContext)))
        userWorker ! getusers //get user is a case object 
      }
   }
} ~ path("users"){
     post{
       entity(as[UserInfo]){
          requestContext => {
          userInfo => {
             val userWorker = actorRefFactory.actorOf(Props(new UserWorker(userservice,requestContext)))
             userWorker ! userInfo
           }
         }
       }
     }
 }
```

My `UserWorker` actor is defined as follows:

```
trait RouteServiceActor extends Actor{
  implicit val system = context.system
  import system.dispatcher
  def processRequest[responseModel:ToResponseMarshaller](requestContex:RequestContext)(processFunc: => responseModel):Unit = {
       Future{
         processFunc
       } onComplete {
          case Success(result) => {
            requestContext.complete(result)
          }
          case Failure(error) => requestContext.complete(error)
       }
  }
}

class UserWorker(userservice: UserServiceComponent#UserService,requestContext:RequestContext) extends RouteServiceActor{
 def receive = {
    case getusers => processRequest(requestContext){
         userservice.getAllUsers
    }
    context.stop(self)
  }
  case userInfo:UserInfo => {
    processRequest(requestContext){
         userservice.createUser(userInfo)
    }
    context.stop(self) 
 }  

}
```

My first question is, am I handling the request in a true asynchronous fashion? What are some of the pitfalls with my code?

My second question is how does the `requestContext.complete` work? Since the original request processing thread is no longer there, how does the `requestContext` send the result of the computation back to the client.

My third question is that since I am calling `context.stop(self)` after each of my partial methods, is it possible that I terminate the worker while it is in the midst of processing a different message.

What I mean is that while the Actor receives a message to process `getusers`, the same actor is done processing `UserInfo` and terminates the Actor before it can get to the "getusers" message. I am creating new actors upon every request, but is it possible that under the covers, the `actorRefFactory` provides a reference to a previously created actor, instead of a new one?

I am pretty confused by all the abstractions and it would be great if somebody could break it down for me.

Thanks

Comment: Besides your original questions on which @jrudolph has already answered : if you want to return some result from your actor to the HTTP user then you should use akka ask pattern:

`(get & path("users")) {
 complete { (userWorker ? getusers).mapTo[PutResultTypeHere] }
}`

And in your UserWorker:
`case getusers => sender ! processRequest(...)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1) Is the request handled asynchronously? Yes, it is. However, you don't gain much with your per-request actors if you immediately delegate the actual processing to a future. In this simple case a cleaner way would be to write your route just as

```
path("users") {
   get {
      complete(getUsers())
   }
}

def getUsers(): Future[Users] = // ... invoke userservice
```

Per-request-actors make more sense if you also want to make route-processing logic run in parallel or if handling the request has more complex requirements, e.g. if you need to query things from multiple service in parallel or need to keep per-request state while some background services are processing the request. See https://github.com/NET-A-PORTER/spray-actor-per-request for some information about this general topic.

2) How does `requestContext.complete` work? Behind the scenes it sends the HTTP response to the spray-can HTTP connection actor as a normal actor message "tell". So, basically the `RequestContext` just wraps an `ActorRef` to the HTTP connection which is safe to use concurrently.

3) Is it possible that "the worker" is terminated by `context.stop(self)`? I think there's some confusion about how things are scheduled behind the scenes. Of course, you are terminating the actor with `context.stop` but that just stops the actor but not any threads (as threads are managed completely independently from actor instances in Akka). As you didn't really make use of an actor's advantages, i.e. encapsulating and synchronizing access to mutable state, everything should work (but as said in 1) is needlessly complex for this use case). The akka documentation has lots of information about how actors, futures, dispatchers, and ExecutionContexts work together to make everything work.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. This was very helpful

Answer (score 2):

In addition to jrudolph answer your spray routing structure shouldn't even compile, cause in your post branch you don't explicitly specify a `requestContext`. This structure can be simplified a bit to this:

```
def spawnWorker(implicit ctx: RequestContext): ActorRef = {
  actorRefFactory actorOf Props(new UserWorker(userservice, ctx))
}

lazy val route: Route = {
  path("users") { implicit ctx =>
    get {
      spawnWorker ! getUsers
    } ~
    (post & entity(as[UserInfo])) { 
      info => spawnWorker ! info 
    }
  }
}
```

The line `info => spawnWorker ! info` can be also simplified to `spawnWorker ! _`.

Also there is an **important point** concerning explicit `ctx` declaration and `complete` directive. If you explicitly declared `ctx` in your route, **you can't use complete directive**, you have to explicitly write `ctx.complete(...)`, [link](https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/276) on this issue

Comment: @Alexlv - I have mixed in the HttpService in the trait where I am defining the route. Shouldn't the requestContext be implicitly defined within the HttpService trait?

Comment: @sc_ray why is that? Take a look at HttService code, and how is that possible if requestContext can be obtained only from the request itself. Actually that what directives are for, take a look at Directive.apply method `apply[L <: Hlist](r: L => Route): Route`, where `Route` is `RequestContext => Unit` function.

Comment: @Alexlv - This is interesting since my code does compile and the request handling is being done the way it is desired.Maybe the implicit is defined in one of my package imports.

Comment: I was talking about `requestContext` in `new UserWorker(userservice,requestContext)` in your post branch. The one you declaring in the `get` branch, shouldn't be visible in the `post` branch. Or am i missing something?

Comment: Oh right..That's a miss. Thanks for pointing that out. I will edit it. I am just confused by who creates the RequestContext that's passed implicitly to the GET/POSTs.